# Is it possible to append to an animated glb object in threejs/aframe?

Tags: animation, three.js, aframe, gltf

I have an object moving about a scene, which I exported as a .glb (model A).

Within Aframe I'm playing the animation on model A using the `animation-mixer` tag and can see the object moving around.  Now what I'm trying to do is append another model (model B), so that model B is also moving around the scene.  However, model B just stays in place - at the specified model A position.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Threejs/Aframe?

I have revisited this technique and have the below code, so far, but the position of the model flickers between it's static position and where it's being set to in the tick.

```
<a-entity id="mantaray-path" gltf-model="#mantaray-path-glb" animation-mixer="timeScale: 1; loop: true;" pathanim></a-entity>
<a-entity id="mantaray" gltf-model="#mantaray-glb" animation-mixer="timeScale: 1;"></a-entity>        

AFRAME.registerComponent("pathanim", {
    init: function() {
        this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', this.update.bind(this));            
    },
    tick: function() {
        this.el.object3D.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child.name == "mantaraypath") {
                mantaray.object3D.position = child.position;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How is your model animated? Via skeletal or morph target animation?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You'll need to share your code (even if it isn't working yet) for us to help you identify what might be going on, and ideally a demo.

Comment: So the animation was a plane moving along a path animation.  I baked the animation to keyframes. When exporting as glb - I believe the top level parent location stays put and it is one of the child elements that is actually moving that I need to append to.